# How to fetch all products without the hidden(private) ones with woocommerce api in python-django?

Tags: python, django, woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api

Having an eshop building with wordpress, i am using the woocommerce api in order to fetch my products in my django app.

I find difficulty in fetching all the products without the hidden - private.

The hidden-private products are those which are not visible in my eshop.

Is there a way through api to fetch all without the hidden?

Here is my code fetching all the products:

```
    wcapi = API(
        url=something,
        consumer_key=something,
        consumer_secret=something,
        wp_api=True,
        version="wc/v2",
        query_string_auth=True,
        verify_ssl = True,
        timeout=10
    )

    #take all the products from the woocommerce api
    r=wcapi.get("products")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check the woocommerce api docs:
https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#list-all-products

You can pass an additional parameter "status" and set it to "publish". The default is "any", that is why private and published products are retrieved.

try this (not tested!):

```
 r=wcapi.get("products", params={"status":"publish"})
```

Comment: After applying this solution I came up with the TypeError: get() got an unexpected keyword argument 'params'

Comment: Do you use the latest version of the library?
I tested my answer and it works. Looking at the code in
https://github.com/woocommerce/wc-api-python/blob/master/woocommerce/api.py
the params dictionary is accepted and send with the request command.
Of course you can also encode it in the url for the request.

Comment: No I don't use the latest version of the library, but the syntax posted in my answer above it worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The right syntax is :

```
r=wcapi.get("products?status=publish")
```